# Rust loop on HashMap while borrowing self

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I have a `Element` struct that implements an update method which takes a tick duration. The struct contains a vector of components. These components are allowed to modify the element on an update. I'm getting a borrow error here and I'm not sure what to do. I tried fixing it with a block, but the block doesn't seems to satisfy the borrow checker.

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::time::Duration;

pub struct Element {
    pub id: String,
    components: HashMap<String, Box<Component>>,
}

pub trait Component {
    fn name(&self) -> String;
    fn update(&mut self, &mut Element, Duration) {}
}

impl Element {
    pub fn update(&mut self, tick: Duration) {
        let keys = {
            (&mut self.components).keys().clone()
        };
        for key in keys {
            let mut component = self.components.remove(key).unwrap();
            component.update(self, Duration::from_millis(0));
        }
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

**The Error**

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `self.components` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:20:33
   |
17 |             (&mut self.components).keys().clone()
   |                   --------------- first mutable borrow occurs here
...
20 |             let mut component = self.components.remove(key).unwrap();
   |                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
...
23 |     }
   |     - first borrow ends here

error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:21:30
   |
17 |             (&mut self.components).keys().clone()
   |                   --------------- first mutable borrow occurs here
...
21 |             component.update(self, Duration::from_millis(0));
   |                              ^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
22 |         }
23 |     }
   |     - first borrow ends here
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`keys()` method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.keys) returns an iterator over the keys in the hashmap.  The `clone()` call only duplicates the iterator, but not the keys themselves.  Your original approach with the `map` function looks promising.  You probably need to collect the result in a `Vec` using the [`collect()` method of the iterator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect):

```
let keys = self.components.keys().cloned().collect::<Vec<_>>();
```

And then:

```
for key in keys {
    self.components.remove(&key).unwrap();
}
```

This ensures that all the keys are copied before the removal operation starts.

Comment: Thanks for your help. That did the trick. I really appreciate it 

Comment: I'd say `self.components.keys().cloned().collect()` is preferred.