# Move a single entry that meets a predicate out of a HashMap when the key is not clonable

Tags: rust, hashmap, borrow-checker

I'm writing a function that works with a `HashMap` and at various points in the function I want to check if any of the values in the map meet a condition and if any does return the key for just one of the entries that meets the condition.

So far, I tried to first iterate over references to check my condition, and then use `remove_entry` to get an owned copy of the key rather than a borrow:

```rust
use std::{collections::HashMap, hash::Hash};

fn remove_first_odd<K: Hash + Eq>(map: &mut HashMap<K, u64>) -> Option<K> {
    let maybe_entry = map.iter().find(|(_, &value)| value & 1 == 1);

    match maybe_entry {
        Some((key_ref, _value_ref)) => {
            let (key_owned, _value_owned) = map.remove_entry(key_ref).unwrap();
            Some(key_owned)
        }
        None => None,
    }
}
```

but this fails borrow checking, because I can't mutate the map while I am still holding a reference to one of the keys in it:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*map` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
 --> src/lib.rs:8:45
  |
4 |     let maybe_entry = map.iter().find(|(_, &value)| value & 1 == 1);
  |                       --- immutable borrow occurs here
...
8 |             let (key_owned, _value_owned) = map.remove_entry(key_ref).unwrap();
  |                                             ^^^^------------^^^^^^^^^
  |                                             |   |
  |                                             |   immutable borrow later used by call
  |                                             mutable borrow occurs here
```

I believe that this is possible, because as long as `remove_entry` only dereferences my key before mutation and not after, this should be sound.

So is there a safe API to do this? If not, can one be created?

Note that:

- I can't clone my keys because they are generic without a clone bound
- I can't consume the `HashMap` with something like `.into_iter()`
- I only need to remove a single entry, not all of the entries that match

Comment: "I can't clone my keys" in which world ? I don't think you can in safe mode.

Comment: I'm afraid it's not possible, at least not if you want to return the key which has been removed. If you do not need to return the value you could use `retain` to remove the pair that fits your criteria.

Comment: @Stargateur I edited it to make it more clear

Comment: @timotree so let me be more clear, key in a hashmap should be clonable in 99% of use case. That very odd situation you have here. I advice you to describe why you can't clone the key.

Comment: See also [How to iterate through a Hashmap, print the key/value and remove the value in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45724517/155423); [Removing items from a BTreeMap or BTreeSet found through iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32913368/155423); [Rust loop on HashMap while borrowing self](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45311896/155423);